# customize debian CD to include local deb, but debian installer installs newer version

Tags: linux

I have build a custom debian CD, which includes some local deb e.g. opera-stable. I am using a specific opera version (ver 58). The CD has my opera-stable_58 correctly. However, during the installation, I find debian installer always try to contact http://dl.opera.com to get newer version of opera (ver 65).

First of all, that operation slow down my installation since accessing dl.opera.com is quite slow here. Secondly, I am happy with the SW version that I am using and don't want to upgrade.

And this situation happens to my other local debs as well. My question is how to stop debian installer from doing that? Basically, I want debian installer to just install the SW package from my custom CD, which I have carefully prepared.

Comment: You need to remove the apt sources that access remote repositories in that case.

Comment: You mean remove mirror from my preseed file? But how does the debian-installer figure out opera source URL? And how can I stop it?

Comment: The opera-stable package (vers 65, no idea about 58 which doesn't appear available) adds the opera repository itself. So depending on when an update is run, the installer could try the opera  repository